# Unable to set read-only property on temp folder

Tags: windows, windows-xp, read-only, temporary-files, file-attributes

I'm trying to make the \documentsettings\user\temp folder as read only to prevent files from writing files into it ( I have reasons to do so). But I've tried all the basic methods of doing so, from the command line using +R on the folder, but it refuses to stay in the read only mode. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to prevent files being created on the temp folder. I don care about applications that would crash if it was denied access into it. In fact, I am testing what applications crash on making it read n

Comment: Can you delete it can create a **file** named TEMP. (Which is not an answer but a work around which might serve your needs).

Comment: are you editing the permissions from the systems administrator account?

Comment: No, as a user. But isn't that enough since I am only modifying my own folder ?

Comment: @Hennes: I would love to try the work-around which you suggest, but unfortunately looks like there are some files in temp which are opened by other processes. I may need to find and close the handles first.

Comment: Booting from  liveCD or putting the drive into an other computer (keeping the original drive int hat computers) would allow you to do so. A really hackish solution, but if you only want to try things once it will work.

Answer (score 1):

The read-only property on folders (+R) does not do what you think on windows.
See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812003

> Windows may also store customization information in ahidden
>   Desktop.ini file in the folder. In this case, Windows sets the
>   read-only attribute on the folder to instruct Windows to look for the
>   Desktop.ini file. The read-only attribute does not prevent you from
>   performing common file and folder tasks (such as copy, move, delete,
>   and rename)

To truly make a folder read-only you need to be on a NTFS file-system and set the permissions on the folder instead which appear under the Security tab (right-click the folder and choose Properties from the menu then select the Security tab). Remove the Modify and Write permissions of each users and group listed from the folder and then no one will be able to write to it.

You may have to click Advanced > Change Permissions and uncheck "Include inheritable permissions ... " to clear SYSTEM permissions that are often inherited from the parent.

Comment: Can this be done as a regular user in WINXP? After all, it is the his folder that he wants to make read-only ?

Comment: Regular user as long as you are the Owner of the folder. If you are not the Owner you must change ownership which will require admin permissions.